# Is there an easy way to have/execute a set of common commands in a terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, ide

Say I have 20-30 common commands. They are not executed in a particular order but the most common commands I use in my work. In some cases, minor changes may be needed to the command before executing.

-I could set up aliases, but I don't like having to remember all of them.

-I could put them in a file, but I don't want to copy and paste a line each time.

-I could search with history, but it is an extra step.

I'd like to have the commands easily displayed and clickable to appear in the command line, and I can execute them. Does such an option exist?

Comment: You can create keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.